# Unable to fire thyristor simscape electrical matlab simulink

Tags: simulink, thyristor

[image]Hello,

I am unable to fire a thyristor on simscape.
I have tried to connect the gate to a pulse generator with a simulink-ps conversion symbol but it doesn't work ( the lines will not connect).
I guess I need to do a controllable voltage or current source but I don't know how to put it in place. Indeed, I would then need to make a whole closed circuit but I can't since my thyristor needs only to be connected through its gate.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simscape to simulink bridge, they are two different solvers. The bridge samples between simulink and simscape. It also has to match the type of units in Simscape

Comment: From what I understood, I added that bridge already with the Simulink-ps connector. Are you implying another bridge ?

Comment: I can't see the block, check your units, you may need to convert it one more time